# How to express $(142536)$ as string of $(13456)$ and $(132)$ in $S_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Suppose that $r=(13456)$ and $s=(132)$ be two permutations in $S_6,$ the group of all permutations of the symbols in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Let $\alpha=(142536)$. I am willing to express $\alpha$ as a string of $r,s$ as $$\alpha=r^{m_1}s^{m_2}r^{m_3}s^{m-4}\cdots$$
where $m_1, m_2, \cdots$ will be integers.

I do not know if there is any general procedure to determine $m_1, m_2, \cdots$ manually.

If any such method exists, please share the link or please tell me how to solve it.

Thanks in advance. Please feel free to edit my question if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this at all. $(142536)$ is an odd permutation, so you cannot write it in terms of even permutations $(13456)$ and $(132)$. Any product of even permutations is itself even.

Comment: I'm sure we have used and explained this same trick elsewhere on our site. Hence CW.

Comment: Thank you. But what if we were given an even permutation ? Can you please explain me with example ?