# Express an even permutation $\alpha$ as a string of $(13456)$ and $(132)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Suppose that $r=(13456)$ and $s=(132)$. Then both are even permutations and are geenrators of $A_6$ which is the alternating group of order 360.

I was curious to know, if we choose any arbitrary even permutation say $\alpha$ from $A_6$, how can we express it as a string of $r,s$ ? In other words, how to find the integers $m_1, m_2, m_3, \cdots$ such that 
$$\alpha=r^{m_1}s^{m_2}r^{m_3}s^{m_4}\cdots $$ would hold ?

I tried to find some method but totally in blank. I have no idea how to get them. Say $\alpha=(14526)$. Can someone help me to get the result ? In case if this problem has been solved before here, please share me the link. I have previously tried a similar problem in this website 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652750/how-to-express-142536-as-string-of-13456-and-132-in-s-6) and got idea that odd permutation cannot be expressed. So I am trying to express even permutation now.

Please help me

Thanking you

Comment: If they are generators of $A_6$ then by definition you can express any element of $A_6$ as a string in them. Actually doing it is another question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes you are right. Is there any method or something like that to get such expression ?

Comment: Well, there's exhaustive search, but that's not much fun (for a human – for a computer, it should be easy).

Comment: ... "of order 360"

Comment: It is surely known how to express the even permutations in terms of $3$-cycles, and indeed of $3$-cycles of the form $(1 2 i)$. I think $(rs)^2 s^2 (rs)^2=(125)$ and you'll get the others by conjugating with $r$.